# Triple nested for loop to be avoided using numpy magic

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, optimization

I have written the following code, which does what I need, but I want to optimize it.

```
import numpy as np
N_rs = 100
N_thetas = 30

Nlm_container = np.ones( (N_thetas, 2*N_thetas-1), dtype=np.complex128 )
lpmv_container = np.ones ( (N_thetas, 2*N_thetas-1, N_thetas), dtype=np.complex128 )
Psi_m_res1 = np.zeros( (2*N_thetas - 1,    N_rs - 1,    N_thetas) , dtype=np.complex128 )
Psi_m_res2 = np.zeros( (2*N_thetas - 1,    N_rs - 1,    N_thetas) , dtype=np.complex128 )
Psi_m_res3 = np.zeros( (2*N_thetas - 1,    N_rs - 1,    N_thetas) , dtype=np.complex128 )
Psi_lm = np.ones ( ( N_rs - 1, 2*N_thetas-1, N_thetas), dtype=np.complex128 )

for m in range(-N_thetas+1,  N_thetas,  1):
    for j in range(N_rs - 1):
        for k in range(N_thetas):
            Psi_m_res1[m + (N_thetas-1),  j,  k] = np.sum(  Psi_lm[j, m+(N_thetas-1), np.abs(m):] * Nlm_container[np.abs(m):, m+(N_thetas-1)]  *  lpmv_container[abs(m):, m+(N_thetas-1), k]  )
```

I want to avoid the triple nested for loop.
I thought that it would be beneficial to use `:`, rather than the loop over `j` and the loop over `k`. I thus wrote (as a first step):

```
for m in range(-N_thetas+1,  N_thetas,  1):
    for k in range(N_thetas):
        Psi_m_res2[m + (N_thetas-1),  :,  k] = np.sum(  Psi_lm[:, m+(N_thetas-1), np.abs(m):] * Nlm_container[np.abs(m):, m+(N_thetas-1)]  *  lpmv_container[abs(m):, m+(N_thetas-1), k]  )
```

Still, this does not produce what I want:

```
print(np.testing.assert_allclose(Psi_m_res1, Psi_m_res2))
Mismatched elements: 175230 / 175230 (100%)
Max absolute difference: 2940.
Max relative difference: 0.98989899
```

Even more, when also eliminating the `k` index for loop, the program does not compute anything at all as the shapes mismatch.

```
for m in range(-N_thetas+1,  N_thetas,  1):
    Psi_m_res3[m + (N_thetas-1),  :,  :] = np.sum(  Psi_lm[:, m+(N_thetas-1), np.abs(m):] * Nlm_container[np.abs(m):, m+(N_thetas-1)]  *  lpmv_container[abs(m):, m+(N_thetas-1), :]  )

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (99,2) (2,30)
```

I could create threads and send pieces of `Psi_lm`, `Nlm_container` and `lpmv_container` to them and ask to perform the work, then reunite the results, but I thought maybe numpy magic would do better.

In practice, the `N_rs` and `N_thetas` would be higher - they can go up to `N_rs = 1600` and `N_thetas=100`, this being set before the code starts to run and fixed throughout the code's runtime.

Is there a way for this to work using numpy magic?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Abhishek, I want to populate the ``Psi_m_res1`` matrix, but more efficiently (faster) than using a triple neste for loop, using 1 core, or if there is a such a method, using multiple cores. Populating the ``Psi_m_res1`` matrix using the new method shall result in filling the matrix with the same values as the inefficient triple for loop above.

Comment: might be a stupid question but what exactly is a Psi_m_res matrxi? Is it a concept? Are there any specific calculations?

Comment: @Abhishek, (almost) no question is stupid in my opinion. for SO purposes, it is a 3D tensor in memory which has to be populated according to some operations, as efficient as possible. For my purposes, it represents the wavefunction of a physical system at one point in its conversion from its spectral representation to its grid representation (I solve 3D TDSE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize the two inner loops using `np.einsum` so to get a much faster code (and simpler). Here is the code:

```py
for m in range(-N_thetas+1,  N_thetas,  1):
    m_abs = np.abs(m)
    idx = m + (N_thetas - 1)
    Psi_m_res1[idx] = np.einsum('ji,i,ik->jk', Psi_lm[:, idx, m_abs:], Nlm_container[m_abs:, idx], lpmv_container[m_abs:, idx, :], optimize='optimal')
```

This takes 4.7 ms on my machine instead of 956 ms. This means the above code is about **200 times faster**! Vectorizing efficiently the outer loop is very hard if not even possible because the array are of different size. Note `np.einsum` is smart enough so to use matrix multiplication internally in this case. If you want a faster code, then I advise you to use a multi-threaded Numba code.

Comment: thank you a lot, I will study your code. Shall I read the fourth line as: ``Psi_m_res1[idx, :, :] = ...`` ?

Comment: Yes, this is an equivalent.

Comment: First of all, this is an impressive analysis of the original code. I think it is possible to vectorize the outer loop. To get rid of the different sized arrays one can use `mask = np.arange(30) >= np.abs(m); Psi_m_res1[idx] = np.einsum('ji,i,ik->jk', Psi_lm[:, idx] * mask, Nlm_container[:, idx] * mask, lpmv_container[:, idx] * mask[:,None], optimize='optimal')`. Building the intermediate arrays would be cumbersome and memory intensive. I doubt it would be faster (on CPU).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Indeed, that an interesting idea. It indeed make the computation memory bound. Also half the computation is not needed (multiplication by 0). That being said, it is worth a try since the overhead of einsum at this granularity is not negligible.